# Kivy: How to place canvas in a specific layout

Tags: python, image, canvas, layout, kivy

I am trying to place an image on a canvas that automatically updates every second. The canvas has a specific source for an image, and whenever the image file gets replaced I have it updated and reloaded on the GUI. No user input, and no exiting of the GUI required.

I was able to get the image to reload, but now I can't place the image where I want to. I want to be able to put it in a layout, preferably located at the top right of the screen

My following main python file is as follows

```
import kivy
import os

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from sshtest import ssh #import the ssh class from the ssh python file


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def login(self): #define login using ssh as a function

        #Make a Class Variable called connection. This allows for other
        #classes to call on it without passing it as an argument

        ScreenOne.connection = ssh("192.168.1.3", "pi", "seniordesign")
                #ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("ls")
        #ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("mkdir thisistest")
        print("Logging in") #For error checking

    def gpioSet(self): #allows for gpio pins to trigger image capture
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("echo '18' > /sys/class/gpio/export")
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand("echo 'out' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction")

class ScreenTwo(Screen): #This is where all the functions are

    def command(self, input): #create a function that sends command through ssh
        ScreenOne.connection.sendCommand(input) #Call on connection made before to send command




class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyPicture(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyPicture,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            MyPicture.picture = Image(source = 'C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/RaspberryPiTransferred/TEST.jpg',
                                      size_hint=(.3,.3))


            #self.add_widget(Image(MyPicture.picture))

    def update(self):
        MyPicture.picture.reload()

    Clock.schedule_interval(update,1)



#Create the Application that will change screens. Add App(App) to end of wanted classname
class ScreenChangeApp(App):

#Create a function that builds the app. Keyword self make sures to reference
#current instantiation

    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name = "screen_one")) 
        screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name = "screen_two"))

        return screen_manager #after building the screens, return them
#MyScreenManager.login()

sample_app = ScreenChangeApp()
sample_app.run()
```

My KV file is shown below

```
#: import os os
<CustomButton@Button>:
    font_size: 12
    size_hint: .2,.1

<Picture@Image>:
    id: image

<ScreenOne>: #define The First Screen
    BoxLayout: #Use box layout
        Button: #create button
            text: "Connect to the Raspberry Pi"
            on_press:
                root.login()
                root.gpioSet()
                root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = "screen_two"

<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        orientation: "vertical"
        CustomButton:
            text: "Send an ls command"
            on_press:
                root.command("ls")

        CustomButton:
            text: "Take picture"
            on_press:
                root.command("python cameradaemon.py &") #'&' runs script in background
                root.command("sleep .1")
                root.command("echo '1' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value") #set pin high to take pic
                root.command("echo '0' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value") #take it off to prevent another photo 

                root.command("scp TEST.jpg Jason@192.168.1.10:C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/RaspberryPiTransferred")          
                root.command("kill %1")



        CustomButton:
            text: "Create Histogram"
            on_press:
                os.system("cd C:/Users/Jason/Desktop/KivyFiles/Histogram & python histogram.py")


    MyPicture
```

What I get is the following GUI Screen [GUI Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiGKF.png).

The image is shown in the bottom left of the screen.

When I press "take picture button" it updates as shown in this screenshot [Image after pic is taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmlld.png)

However I don't have the control over the placement like I want to.

Originally I had the image appear on the top right of the screen with different code, but I was not able to update the image dynamically [Older GUI placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4eNu.png)

My previous code set that image in an anchor layout, but it was static. Now that I'm using a canvas, it updates with my current code, but I can't place it like I did before.

The part where I set "size_hint" does not do anything, I was just guessing and checking at this point.

Is there any easier way to call that Picture class in the KV class so that the image is set in a specific layout? For example

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'right'
    anchor_y: 'left'
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        Image:
            <Dynamic image goes here>
```

Where instead of "Dynamic image goes here"  I had

```
source: <location of image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another BoxLayout with the horizontal(default) orientation:

```
<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: .5
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            orientation: "vertical"

            ...

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y:'top'
            MyPicture:
                size_hint_y: .5
```

withis code I get the output:

[image: output]

but sincerily I prefer use a floatlayout and fix the pos and size myself

something like this with the float layout:

```
<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: .5
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            orientation: "vertical"

            ...

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_x: .5
            MyPicture:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .5} #edit this like you want
```

Comment: I added that into my kv file but I still end up with the image appearing on the bottom left of the screen

Comment: In the code you show you have the image file with a source. This means it is static. I need that image file to update every second. My code takes an image and replaces the image file at that source.

I've used the method you've shown but I don't know how to make it so that the image file keeps updating

Comment: @Jason please try this code with yout "static" image and tell me if it works before trying it with a dynamic image

Comment: If it doesn't work then the solution is to use a float layout instead of the anchor layout